# how to install wowza on cpanel

Tags: stream, streaming, video-streaming, wowza

i tried to use wowza , now i use it on localhost and use webcam to stream video successfully from my pc only .
so i tried to use it on my web server but i searched alot and cannot find any thing help me to install wowza manager over cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need root privileges to install Wowza on your web server.  There isn't a cpanel mechanism (or embedded installer) that will setup Wowza for you.  You would [set it up](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217-How-to-install-and-configure-Wowza-Streaming-Engine) in the same fashion that you did [locally](https://www.wowza.com/pricing/installer).

Thanks,
Matt